# Display multiple blocks in 2 lines with a specific order

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hey I'm actually doing a site with the possibility to connect to multiple services to create some Actions/Reactions. I generalized the display of my services and it's working but I encountered a problem. I canno't display them the way I wanted ( cf the image ).
They are all in one  component cause of the generalization.

This is my actual display :
[image: ![enter image description here]

And this is the final result I want :
[image]

There is my react function in case you need it :

```
function Services() {
return (
    <div className="Services">
        {ServicesContent.map((val, key) => {
            return (
                <a className="SingleService" href={val.link}>
                    <div class="ServiceBg">
                        <img src={require("../../img/" + val.logo + ".png")} class="ServiceLogo"/>
                    </div>
                </a>    
            )
        })}   
    </div>
)
}
```

And this is my CSS file :

```css
    .Services {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.SingleService {
  margin-bottom: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 163, 0);
  background-color: #EDEDED;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 14vh;
  border-radius: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.ServiceBg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ServiceLogo {
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

So if you have any idea that can help me to delete the gap, thank you in advance.

Comment: `I canno't display them the way I wanted` <--- In what way do you want to display them? Also your class is called `Services` but in your component you are calling a class `Service`

Comment: Ive converted your code to an interactive snippet. I did have to correct some invalid HTML though, such as duplicate `id="logo"` and `id="bg"` attributes - I changed them to `class=""`.

Comment: @GhostOrder I did some changes in my question I hope it's more comprehensible now.
And yeah for my classname components I know it's invalid, it was temporary cause I have no idea how I can name them.

Comment: @Dai I don't understand why this 2 attributes are invalid HTML and why I should change them to an empty string class. What's the difference ?

Comment: @Vroxy `id=""` has to be unique within the entire page: it's incorrect to have 2 or more elements sharing the same `id=""` attribute value. I'm not too familiar with Reactjs, can you confirm if React handles ensuring unique `id=""` attributes in emitted JSX?

Comment: @Dai yeah you right and I didn't know that, thank you for the advice. I just changed them to class attribute and modify the Logo name ( Already have one, this is why i put them in id attribute instead of class ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make the height fixed and exactly make the mapped element size half of the parent element container and use flex in column and wrap it. Height should be made 50% of the  parent

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content:flex-start;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 80vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 38vh;
  margin:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child1</div>
  <div class="child">child2</div>
  <div class="child">child3</div>
  <div class="child">child4</div>
  <div class="child">child5</div>
  <div class="child">child6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay thank you. It's start to look like the result I wanted, I'm gonna update my question so you can see the remaining problem. And thank you for the responsive tip.

Comment: I made the changes to remove the gap. You can use the `align-content` to `flex-start` on the parent to remove the gap and to add spacing if required between elements you can add margin to them, just make sure the total height or width doesn't exceed the containers height/width